# Пара вопросов по tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, button

Я решил ознакомиться с библиотекой tkinter python. Начал читать статью и мне в ней кое что непонятно помогите пожалуйста(я новичок в пайтоне)

Вот код:

```
from tkinter import *
def button_clicked():
    print (u"Клик!")
root=Tk()

button1 = Button()
button1.pack()

button2 = Button(root, bg="red", text=u"Кликни меня!", command=button_clicked)
button2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

1. Мне не ясно что такое u перед текстом
2. Что такое root = Tk()
3. button1 = Button()

Comment: Может сначала стоит изучить питон, а уже потом переходить к конкретным библиотекам?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `u` используется для обозначения строки Unicode (в Python 3 это не обязательно, в нем и так строки Unicode).
2. Создается объект класса `Tk` и присваивается переменной `root`.
3. То же, что и в (2). Только создается объект класса `Button` и присваивается переменной `button1`.